# How to pass Hyperlinkfield text inside the Grid view from one page to another page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i  am having one gridview with the hyperlinkfields column.
now i want the text of selected hyperlink, in another page(Home2.aspx)

home.aspx

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="UserName" HeaderText ="User Name" DataNavigateUrlFields="UserName" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="<%# Eval("UserName", "~/TimeTracker/home2.aspx") %>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle it on row_command, and then send it as query string with response.redirect or put it is session variable and use that in other page.

find the control and assign it new instance of control, then grab the value and send it to other page.